# 2D array of objects YAML to Java

Tags: java, arrays, yaml

I'm trying to deserialize a 2D array in Java that I put together in YAML. I'm using the Yamlbeans library for this.

Here's my YAML:

```
states:
 - 0:
  - name: SPAWNINGSTATE
    duration: 4
```

Here's my class:

```
public class State {
    public String name;
    public long duration;

    public State(){}

    public State(String name, long duration){
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;

    }
}
```

Array is declared in another class with just one line:

```
public State[][] states;
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader$YamlReaderException: Line 57, column 5: Error creating object.
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:266)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:152)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:335)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:152)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:295)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:152)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:103)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:90)
    at com.sbg.wickedtemplate.layers.ForegroundLightning.<init>(ForegroundLightning.java:22)
    at com.sbg.wickedtemplate.World.<init>(World.java:25)
    at com.sbg.wickedtemplate.LWP_Engine.create(LWP_Engine.java:39)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: Unable to find a no-arg constructor for class: [Lcom.sbg.wickedtemplate.State;
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.Beans.createObject(Beans.java:111)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.createObject(YamlReader.java:363)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:264)
```

I had no issues making a regular array. Why is it telling me that it can't find a no-arg constructor, when it's clearly there? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try fixing one of your nodes?

```
    states:
       0:
         name: SPAWNINGSTATE
         duration: 4
```

the "-" makes it an array it may be throwing it off.